# Not able to update multiple rows in Oracle at a time

Tags: oracle, join, sql-update

I am trying to execute an update query in a table where I am trying to insert foreign key for some table,

**Query is:**

```
update TABLE_1 set TABLE_2_ID = (select TABLE_2_ID from TABLE_2)
```

**Getting Exception:**

> caused by : "ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

I have googled the problem I know the problem is I have multiple result rows from **select TABLE_2_ID from TABLE_2** which I am trying to update in a single row, but I have not been able to identify the result.

Comment: what is relation between both table?

Comment: Parent (Table_1, trying to insert primary_key of Table_2 as foreign_key), Child (Table_2)

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE] including DDL statements for your tables and some sample data with demonstrates the problem and your expected output from the update.

Comment: "trying to insert primary_key" - no, you're trying to update existing rows. So which do you really want to do? If inserting, do you want one child per parent? If updating, are you setting all values to the same ting, and if not how do you decide with ID to use for each row?

Answer (score 1):

Add a line of code in `"update TABLE_1 set TABLE_2_ID = (select TABLE_2_ID from TABLE_2 where XXXXX)"` to make sure `(select TABLE_2_ID from TABLE_2 where XXXXX)` return only one result

> **or like this**

```
update  TABLE_1
　　set (TABLE_1.a2,TABLE_1.a3) =(select TABLE_2.b2,TABLE_2.b3
　　from  TABLE_2
　　where TABLE_2.b1= TABLE_1.a1 and TABLE_1.a3=xxx
　　)
where exists
(select 'X' from TABLE_2 where TABLE_2.b1=TABLE_1.a1 and TABLE_1.a3=xxx);
commit;
```